# VBA Code for Making Entire Rows Bold based on a Cell value in the Query table

Tags: excel, vba, sap-query

I have a table in the range (`G15:AL540`) generated through SAP Query. I need to make all the rows Bold if the Cells in Column `L` Contains the word "Main Investigation". I did it using Conditional Formatting (`=$L16="Main investigation"`) and it worked. But I need to write it in VBA, so that this formatting is applied automatically when the Query is refreshed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will only work for active sheet, change activesheet to sheets("sheetabc") to reference another sheet

```
Sub test()
With ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In .Range("G15:" & .Range("G15").End(xlDown).Address)
        If .Cells(cell.Row, 12).Value = "Main investigation" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you make it as the answer if it has worked for you. little tick to the left of the post